# Why doesn't pugixml write back to the currently opened file?

Tags: c++, pugixml

The following code is basically everything I'm doing - opening an XML file, processing it and (trying to) write it back. But writing back fails, every time. I tried to find a solution wrote code, Googled, but got no answer.

```
xml_parse_result result = doc.load_file("data.xml");
//I checked the value of result, it is equal to status_ok, so the file opened fine.
//...
//some XML processing
//...
bool b = doc.save_file("data.xml"); //b is always false
```

So, is it like pugi doesn't close the file after taking in the input or what? That doesn't seem to be the case as I can delete the file while the program is running. Does anyone know why my program reads the file but doesn't write the modifications back into it?

Comment: Downvote? This is a legitimate question and I did try to find an answer. Mind explaining the reason for the downvote?

Comment: There can be many reasons why save_file fails: 1. current folder changed to point to non-writeable location (e.g. open file dialog can do that behind your back), 2. data.xml is read-only (most likely case, I'd say), 3. you are opening other files between load_file and save_file and not closing them which leaks file descriptors.

Comment: To diagnose this, you should print errno (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cerrno/errno/) after save_file fails - it may have an error code.

Comment: @zeuxcg Yeah, you're right. data.xml is indeed read-only. This is quite surprising for me. Thanks a lot. I've managed to solve this problem using `setPermissions(QFile::ReadOther | QFile::WriteOther);`.

Comment: I don't get what this downvote is for. Upvotes, so you are alt least back at 0 now.

Comment: Also: the answer from @Cassio solved it for me, since mine was't read only. Completely legit question!

Answer (score 2):

Try loading the file from an ifstream. This way you have control over the file, and can be sure when it is closed.

```
// Initialization code
{
  std::ifstream stream("data.xml");
  pugi::xml_parse_result result = doc.load(stream);
  // Check validity
} // Input stream implicitly destructed and file closed.
// Processing
{
  std::ofstream stream("data.xml");
  doc.save(stream);
} // Output stream implicitly destructed and file closed.
```

As to why this happens... The [Documentation](http://pugixml.org/docs/manual.html#loading.file) isn't explicit about it, so it's hard to tell. It seems that it should close the file after loading, but the only way to be sure is by looking at the source code. BTW, if you're on a linux OS, you should be able to delete opened files.

Comment: Yeah, that's a worthy alternative. I read the code and `fclose` _is_ passed as a function pointer in the corresponding calls. So, technically it should close the file after reading. And yeah, I'm on Windows that's why I added that as a _proof_ that the file is not open. Thanks for trying to help! There are a lot of bullies in SO, who downvote a question right away when they notice someone with a low rep ask something they can't answer.